# In android app using phone gap after paypal connection(sandbox) how to redirect into my app home page

Tags: javascript, android

i was developing  android app using phone gap(javascript) .....

in my application  after pay pal connection(sandbox) how to redirect into my app home page
after payp al connection my process was success but after that the process completed it redirect into my url site i want to redirect into my html page that is payment successfully displayed

in my application  after pay pal connection(sandbox) how to redirect into my app home page
after payp al connection my process was success but after that the process completed it redirect into my url site i want to redirect into my html page that is payment successfully displayed

Comment: Pay pal gateway is open in webview or browser?

Comment: Paypal gateway is open in webview only.-Ramesh kannan